# Tooltipster initialisation error with "sideTip" plugin

Tags: jquery, tooltipster

I'm trying to use **tooltipster** https://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/ but I'm facing a problem.

I loaded correctly \js\vendor\tooltipster\tooltipster.bundle.min.js and \less\vendor\tooltipster\tooltipster.bundle.min.less.

But when I'm calling it :

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster({
         animation: 'fade',
         delay: 200,
         triggerOpen: {
            click: true,  // For mouse
            tap: true    // For touch device
         },
      });
```

> tooltipster-52452b94.js:7623 Uncaught Error: The "sideTip" plugin is not defined
>
> at a.Tooltipster._plug (tooltipster-52452b94.js:7623)

Did I forget anything? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I solved it by loading **\js\vendor\tooltipster\tooltipster.bundle.js** instead of **\js\vendor\tooltipster\tooltipster.bundle.min.js**